# How to add a link to edit and delete each row in a table formulated using php

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table, crud

I have written php code that outputs a php table and for each row, I want to be able to add an extra column to an edit and delete link (CRUD functionality). Currently I have been able to add the extra column but I am unsure on how to actually add the edit and update links in each row. My table currently looks like this.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwFzQ.png

The table is made using html code and the data is received using php code that is linked to another file. The following is the html code,

```
      <table class="content-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Cashflow</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php include_once('data.php'); ?>

      </tbody>
  </table>
```

The following is the php code (data.php):

```
      while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($output)) {
    echo "<tr><td>". $data["cashflow"] ."</td><td>". $data["amount"] ."</td><td>". $data["description"] ;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `<a href="...">something</a>` yet?

Comment: Edit and update links? Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: @user3783243 how would I incorporate that in the php echo code?

Comment: @El_Vanja sorry I meant edit and delete. I have made the necessary corrections in the question.

Comment: Same way you've done the `td` but either escape the double quotes or use single quotes for encapsulation. It sounds like you might need to read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some ID from database example: $data["id"]

```
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($output)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $data["cashflow"] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $data["amount"] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $data["description"]."</td>";
    echo '<td><a href="URL TO EDIT?id='.$data["id"].'">Edit</a></td>';
  }
```

Comment: Don't need 5 echos. https://3v4l.org/kGcUV (Ignore error)

Comment: I specially wrote that it was clean and clear. Because its code is not readable